# Prediction on mixed effect models: what to do with random effects?

Tags: mixed-model, linear-model, prediction

Let's consider this hypothetical dataset:

```
set.seed(12345)

num.subjects <- 10

dose <- rep(c(1,10,50,100), num.subjects)
subject <- rep(1:num.subjects, each=4)
group <- rep(1:2, each=num.subjects/2*4)

response <- dose*dose/10 * group + rnorm(length(dose), 50, 30)

df <- data.frame(dose=dose, response=response, 
                 subject=subject, group=group)
```

we can use `lme` to model the response with a random effect model:

```
require(nlme)
model <- lme(response ~ dose + group + dose*group, 
             random = ~1|subject, df)
```

I would like to use `predict` on the result of this model to get, for instance, the response of a generic subject of group 1 to a dose of 10:

```
pred <- predict(model, newdata=list(dose=10, group=1))
```

However, with this code I get the following error:

```
Error in predict.lme(model, newdata = list(dose = 10, group = 1)) : 
cannot evaluate groups for desired levels on 'newdata'
```

To get rid of it I need to do, for instance

```
pred <- predict(model, newdata=list(dose=10, group=1, subject=5))
```

This, however, does not really make much sense to me... the subject is a nuisance factor in my model, so what sense does it have to include it in `predict`? If I put a subject number not present in the dataset, `predict` returns `NA`.

Is this the wanted behaviour for `predict` in this situation? Am I missing something really obvious?

Comment: I think you are looking for a population response rather than a mean prediction. The unconditional `model` does assume that your mean is given by $X\beta + Z\gamma$  (in particular $y \sim N(X\beta+Z\gamma, \sigma^2 I)$ so it will expect some values for the *nuisance* parameter also. There are situations that it might not even make sense to assume your evaluation point is hierarchy-free (so no $Z$). That's why fitted() gives you results "with nuisance" in the first place. (And actually I don't think it nuisance but rather a extra info but OK...)

Comment: @user11852: just to clarify, I am thinking about this as a model to be used, for instance, in case of repeated measures for the same subject.

Comment: Given you are are looking estimates for the same subject, why exclude it then? If you want population level estimates (no $Z$ information) then it is a difference question. As Greg says in his response you can get estimates for the population if you want but that won't be subject specific.

Comment: @user11852: I am not looking for estimate on the same subject. I do repeated measures on various subjects in order to get population estimates. I do not care for the subjects that I already tested as I already have the experimental answer... I want to be able to predict how a new subject of a specific group will respond to the stimulus. Greg answer solves the problem indeed.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you look at the help for `predict.lme` you will see that it has a `level` argument that determines which level to make the predictions at.  The default is the highest or innermost which means that if you don't specify the level then it is trying to predict at the subject level.  If you specify `level=0` as part of your first `predict` call (without `subject`) then it will give the prediction at the population level and not need a subject number.